# Github for Mac: Pull Request Button is missing

Tags: github, github-for-mac

Saturday I installed Github Desktop on my Mac and tried the Github Workflow. Created a branch, committed changes and did a Pull Request. Everything worked.

Today I installed Github for Mac at work - and the Pull Request Button is no where to be found. I'm back home now on my private Mac and the button is missing here as well now.

As you can see on the last screenshot, the branch is up on github.com and ready for a PR. Also the dots in Github for Desktops Timeline (top right) are small, which means the commits are pushed. And there are changes to the dev branch (second screenshots).

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Update: maybe my branch isn't eligible for a PR? Because the menu item is also greyed out:

[image]

I have two branches, they have committed (and pushed) differences... hm.

Comment: Not sure, but if there are no changes  between your local repo/branch and the remote (github), then you cannot create a pull request and therefor no reason to show you the PR button?

Comment: A Pull Request isn't about changes between local and remote branch. It's about differences between two branches. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: just to be sure I added another screenshot with comparison to the `dev` branch

Comment: yes it is changes between branches, but if you haven't pushed the changed branch to the remote yet, the remote doesn't know about.

Comment: sure I did. Otherwise it would say "Publish" where it says "Sync" now. And the dots in the timeline would be bigger for "unpushed commits".
added another Screenshot from github.com to show that the branch is up there and ready for a pull request

Comment: gotcha, out of ideas then. did you push from inside github for mac or outside? (assuming sync doesn't help)

Comment: pushed from inside github.com via "sync". Pushing and Pulling works (via Sync). Just the Pull Request is missing.

Comment: I faced same issue too few times (also with synced repos). Simple restart of an app usually helps. But still don't know why does pr button periodically disappear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way of doing this (it worked for me) is to go to:

"Preferences" > "Sign out" > "Sign in" (again)

That way you'll reset your Github desktop (don't worry. You won't lose anything :) )

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it. As you can see in the screenshots my repository is marked as "other". That's because it was already on my machine and I've not cloned it in Github for Desktop. I just added it.

I cloned that repository as follows

`https://githubusername:githubpassword@github.com/organization/repo.git`

That URL as `remote.origin.url` probably isn't handled by Github for Desktop so the Repo is marked as "other".

Weird. I recloned my repositories and now everything is working fine.

Comment: I've got similar problem although my repository was marked as "GitHub". I had the repository already cloned before installing Github Desktop. The solution was to go to the "Preferences > Accounts" and sign in with GitHub credentials. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this is my own issue which is a specific case:

On linux:

my friend gave a laptop to me.

I had a same issue on my friend's laptop that he gave it to me with his github credentials. I did change my username and email in the `git config --global`  and I send a PR, but I didn't see the `compare and pull request` button. I

I asked him and he was able to see the `compare and pull request` button.

I remove his `~./ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `~./ssh/id_rsa` public and his private keys, and replace it with my own laptop public and his private keys. and it worked.

it's like when you login to github, github saves your public key.

so I was able to see the button.