# GitHub client: Pull Request Button is missing

Tags: git, github, pull-request, github-for-windows

I use GitHub client for Bitbucket repository. All work & sync correctly, but Pull Request button not showing. In GitHub repo all works.

I found simular issue - [Github for Mac: Pull Request Button is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615099/github-for-mac-pull-request-button-is-missing), but I use Bitbucket and can't change repo marker from "other".

Any proposal?

GitHub:

[image]

Other repo:

[image]

Comment: same issue here, did you ever find out why?

Comment: @r3plica from official github support ( support@github.com ): 

"In order to create a pull request the repository must exist on GitHub.com." 

and 

"There is a button called 'View Branch' beside the update from master button.

If you click this, the 'View from Master' button should change to 'Compare'.

If you click this button you should see a list of branches you can choose from to merge!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer from official github support ( support@github.com ):

> In order to create a pull request the repository must exist on
>   GitHub.com.

and

> There is a button called 'View Branch' beside the update from master
>   button.
>
> If you click this, the 'View from Master' button should change
>   to 'Compare'.
>
> If you click this button you should see a list of
>   branches you can choose from to merge!

Answer (score 4):

Anyone stumped on this:

Check that you are logged in.

It sounds obviously but github allows browsing around and checking if two branches will merge, but you won't be able to actually create a request without an account. The only difference will be the button not being there.

Comment: OH MY GOD. This was it! Thank you. It was driving me CRAZY. Maybe github would benefit from having a merge button that nags you to log in first or says you don't ahve rights. It took me so long to realize I wasn't in my normal browser and wasn't logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a similar issue in below case.

1. I was using GitHub Windows client
2. I was using the repository which was associated with account X.
3. X moved that repository to another account called Y.

Now onward, I was able to perform normal operation like creating new branch, push, sync etc button Pull Request button was not visible for those repository which has moved from account X to Y.

Solution:- It was happening because remote URL in my windows client was still pointing to old account repository, so I have changed that to new account repository and restarted the windows client and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

this is my own issue which is a specific case:

On linux:

my friend gave a laptop to me.

I had a same issue on my friend's laptop that he gave it to me with his github credentials. I did change my username and email in the `git config --global`  and I send a PR, but I didn't see the `compare and pull request` button. I

I asked him and he was able to see the `compare and pull request` button. so I send a PR and he saw the button which it was weird.

I remove his `~./ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `~./ssh/id_rsa` public and his private keys, and replace it with my own laptop public and his private keys. and it worked.

it's like when you login to github, github saves your public key.

so I was able to see the button again.