# Github for Windows Pull Request for remote Bitbucket Repo

Tags: github-for-windows

Based on [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664949/use-github-for-windows-for-both-bitbucket-and-github/13665100?noredirect=1#comment66365224_13665100) I was able to successfully connect Github for Desktop with my remote Bitbucket repo.

Looking at the example tutorial repo I see there is an Pull Request option built in the application - great:

[image]

However the option is missing when I chose my remote Bitbucket repo:

[image]

I couldn't find any option that is reponsible for this.

Anyone knows what affects this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pull Request" is very much a GitHub feature, [associated to GitHub repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343356/6309).

So For BitBucket, the simplest approach is to push your feature branch to the remote repo (which is a BitBucket one, not a GitHub one), and make your PR from there ([from the remote BitBucket web GUI](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/create-a-pull-request-774243413.html#Createapullrequest-Step2.Createapullrequest), even [within the same repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-pull-requests-in-bitbucket-server-776639997.html))

[image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/files/808488431/813893206/1/1456788498243/image2015-7-28+10-25-9.png]

Once the PR is initiated, each push done from the GitHub Desktop will complete said PR.

Answer (score 2):

In Bitbucket go to Settings -> Branch Permissions, and add a new branch permission with your name.

**EDIT**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343356/1544886